# Android run a task every 4 second

Tags: java, android, multithreading

Hi i need to call a method every 4 seconds, even when the device is sleeping, i use alarm manager with service Start_stick, the service name is TransactionService. the code works well when the device is active and the method is called every exact 4 second, but when the screen is locked and device sleep the calling becomes inaccurate. so the method is now called every 2 seconds, sometimes every 1 sec,5 ....

this is how i run the thread to call method every 4 seconds

```
    AlarmManager mgr = (AlarmManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(
            Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                TransactionService.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(
                getApplicationContext(), 0, notificationIntent, 0);
        mgr.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
                System.currentTimeMillis(), 4000, pendingIntent);
```

this is the log of calling the method when device is active and screen is on

```
12-30 13:23:00.565 17397-17479/com.ids.simcardrefill D/url: calling
 12-30 13:23:04.565 17397-17537/com.ids.simcardrefill D/url:calling
 12-30 13:23:08.565 17397-17411/com.ids.simcardrefill D/url:calling
 12-30 13:23:12.565 17397-17655/com.ids.simcardrefill D/url:calling
```

and this is how the method is calling when device is sleeping

```
12-30 13:09:12.565 17397-17655/com.ids.simcardrefill D/url:calling
12-30 13:09:17.785 17397-17598/com.ids.simcardrefill D/url:calling
12-30 13:09:20.565 17397-17479/com.ids.simcardrefill D/url:calling
12-30 13:09:25.775 17397-17537/com.ids.simcardrefill D/url:calling
12-30 13:09:28.565 17397-17411/com.ids.simcardrefill D/url:calling
```

here the difference between calling is inaccurate: 2 seconds, 5 seconds, 3 seconds

this is how the service look like :

```
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {


    mshared = PreferenceManager
            .getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
    edit = mshared.edit();
    hostname = mshared.getString(
            getApplicationContext().getString(R.string.hostname), "0");
    contin = true;
    cost
   = mshared.getString(getString(R.string.test), "0.09");
            if (contin) {
                getTransactions get = new    getTransactions(getApplicationContext());
                get.execute(hostname);
            }

    return START_STICKY;
}
```

`

any solution ??

Comment: use wake log to achieve that.

Comment: Hi Malo, you can you used service in the foreground and call your AlarmManger task just like startForgroundService(true),http://www.truiton.com/2014/10/android-foreground-service-example/

Comment: The the timing becomes "inaccurate" is caused by Android (6.0+) which bundles network activities to larger batches to save battery time. Anyway if you need to perform an online-call every 4 seconds something may be wrong with the design of the API. Polling something every 4 seconds is bad style like busy waiting.

Comment: the device is here to work in this app only, and it is connected to charge all the time, also the os is 4.4.1 not 6.0+ .

Comment: please don't do this. App will slurp batteries and nobody will like it. Whatever you are trying to do, there is another way.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should crate a service for working in background: https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html

You should use `Handler` in order to implement `every 4 second` functionality.

```
Handler handler = new Handler();
Runnable test = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        //do work
        handler.post(test, 4000); //wait 4 sec and run again
    }
};

public void stopTest() {
    handler.removeCallbacks(test);
}

public void startTest() {
    handler.post(test,0); //wait 0 ms and run
}
```

EDIT: i have tried the code below and it works for me

**MyService.java**

```
public class MyService extends Service {
    Handler handler;
    Runnable test;
    public MyService() {
        handler = new Handler();
        test = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Log.d("foo", "bar");
                handler.postDelayed(test, 100); //100 ms you should do it 4000
            }
        };

        handler.postDelayed(test, 0);
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<service
    android:name=".MyService"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:exported="true"></service>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    //some code
    startService(new Intent(this, MyService.class));
}
```

And remember if you want **start-stop** functionality take loot at my first example.

Comment: i already try it, after a while the loop stopped. i think because the device is sleeping

Comment: Did you implement a service or it is just an application?

Comment: also i who you how i call it every 4 second

Comment: you say handler.post(test, 4000); in the run method of test runnable

Comment: If you post what you have tried someone might offer a solution (like EDIT: i have tried this with services and handlers)

Comment: i have tried this `ScheduledExecutorService scheduleTaskExecutor = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(5);


  scheduleTaskExecutor.scheduleAtFixedRate(new Runnable() {
   public void run() {
    if (contin) {
     getTransactions get = new getTransactions(getApplicationContext());
     get.execute(hostname);
    }

   }
  }, 0, 4, TimeUnit.SECONDS);`

Comment: Edited my answer with a code block that works well for me

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to do this is using a Handler *(as already mentioned in the other answer)*, but I will take the liberty to add a few points to it.

### The problem

I had a similar situation, where the AlarmManager was firing erratically. Digging deeper into the issue led to me to understand that since the AlarmManager operation wakes up the CPU by holding a CPU wake-lock and is intensive on the battery (given that the device is inactive), the OS tries to batch different alarms from different apps and fires all pending alarms when the device wakes up. This leads to the erratic behaviour of the AlarmManager. The documentation also specifies that we shouldn't be using this to trigger events at **exact** timestamps. There are Android APIs which are supposed to work for exact intervals, eg **[AlarmManager.setExact()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#setExact(int,%20long,%20android.app.PendingIntent))**, but the OS optimises itself to ignore the exactness if the interval duration is less than a minute. *[not documented, but speaking from my personal experiences]*

### The fix

I fixed the issue using a Handler only, as shared in the other answer. But there is a small caveat. In the edge case that the Handler is killed (due to any reason), it won't trigger itself and your polling would stop.

### The caveat

The fallback is to keep a AlarmManager as well, running every minute to trigger the Handler back again in case it was stopped prematurely by the OS. So, you have a Handler running every n seconds. Store the timestamp of the last time the Handler was called in SharedPreferences. Have a backup AlarmManager running every x minutes (ideally x = 5*n, so that you don't miss more than 5 polling calls). The AlarmManager checks when the Handler last ran. If it's within the margin, the AlarmManager does nothing and reschedules itself after x minutes. If it's been more than x minutes, the Handler must have been killed by the OS and the AlarmManager starts the Handler back again.

Adding some code to give you context as well.

```
public class PollingAlarmReceiver extends WakefulBroadcastReceiver {

    final long POLLING_FREQUENCY_MARGIN = 5 * 1000; //margin kept in case the System delays any threads

    Context mContext = ServicesApp.getContext();


    /*
    Splash/BootReceiver starts the Alarm and the Handler for polling.
    The Handler starts the polling service and schedules the next run after an delay of the polling interval.
    Before starting the service, the Handler also checks when the service was last run and whether it is time for the next call or not (with a margin of 5 seconds [POLLING_FREQUENCY_MARGIN]).
    The Handler should cover all the cases and run smoothly. In case it fails, the Alarm acts as a failsafe.
    The Alarm runs at an interval of 1 minute checking when the Handler was last called.
    If it is past the time of the next scheduled call (with a margin of 5 seconds [POLLING_FREQUENCY_MARGIN]), the Alarm starts the runnable and makes the Handler queue the next run.
    */

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        if (mContext == null)
            mContext = ServicesApp.getContext();

        if (mContext == null)
            mContext = context.getApplicationContext();

        if (mContext != null) {
            if (getLastPolledTimestamp(mContext) > 0 && (System.currentTimeMillis() > (POLLING_FREQUENCY_MARGIN +  getPollingInterval(mContext) + getLastPolledTimestamp(mContext)))) {
                startPollingHandler();
            }
        }
    }


    Runnable mPoller = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

            if (mContext == null)
                mContext = ServicesApp.getContext();
            if (mContext != null) {
                try {
                    if ((System.currentTimeMillis() >= (getPollingInterval(mContext)) - POLLING_FREQUENCY_MARGIN + getLastPolledTimestamp(mContext))) {
                        if (!isServiceRunning(PollingService.class, mContext)) {
                            mContext.getSharedPreferences(CommonLib.APP_SETTINGS, 0).edit().putLong(LAST_POLLED_TIMESTAMP, System.currentTimeMillis()).commit();
                            Intent service = new Intent(mContext, PollingService.class);
                            startWakefulService(mContext, service);
                        }
                    }
                } finally {
                    ServicesApp.getHandler().postDelayed(mPoller, getPollingInterval(mContext));
                }
            }
        }
    };

    public void startAlarmToCheckForHandler() {
        if (mContext == null)
            mContext = ServicesApp.getContext();
        if (mContext != null) {
            AlarmManager alarmMgr = (AlarmManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
            Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, PollingAlarmReceiver.class);
            PendingIntent alarmIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(mContext, 0, intent, 0);
            alarmMgr.setRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP, SystemClock.elapsedRealtime(), 60 * 1000, alarmIntent);

        }
    }

    public void startPollingHandler() {
        mPoller.run();

    }

    public void cancelAlarm() {
        if (mContext == null)
            mContext = ServicesApp.getContext();
        if (mContext != null) {
            AlarmManager alarmMgr = (AlarmManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
            Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, PollingAlarmReceiver.class);
            PendingIntent alarmIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(mContext, 0, intent, 0);
            alarmMgr.cancel(alarmIntent);
        }
    }
}
```

**P.S. :** I have this code running on production for thousand of devices whose main functionality rely on the exactness of the polling and it seems to be working great for me.